# Replacement Ignitor in Gas Oven burned out on first run

Tags: oven

I've got a GE CGS990 gas oven that's been working well for the past year.

On sunday (of course) the bottom oven stopped getting hot; I took it apart and found the ignitor was clearly broken (small crack).  The broken part is probably a generic part -- it had ceramic wire nuts attaching it to the oven's wiring.

Today I replaced the ignitor with a generic unit from the repair shop down the street.  Both are flat looking ignitor elements.  The cranky old man at the shop assured me they were all the same (ignitors, and possibly cranky old men who run appliance repair shops).

I replaced it and (foolishly) put the oven back together.

When I turned the oven on, I could see the glow of the ignitor, then the gas valve opened and the burners came on; after about 45 - 60 seconds, the glow got brighter and brighter and turned from orange to white, then there was a popping sound and the oven turned off the gas flow.  The new ignitor was broken in two places; nothing else looked amiss so I don't think there were any shorts or other issues with the replacement.

At this point, I'm not sure if I should throw another ignitor at the problem or call in a professional.  I'm not sure if the different ignitors are actually the same or if there are differences beyond the mounting bracket and connectors.

Thoughts?

Comment: Could be a problem with the circuitry that powers the igniter. Could be a problem with the flame sensor. If you're not comfortable troubleshooting the issue further, it might be time to take it to the grumpy old man at the repair shop.

Comment: So the "flat ignitor" ignition units are basically alike other than the bracket that holds them in place?  (I reused the original bracket).  If that's the case, I'm not really on-board with trying to debug this oven much more.  I assume the ignitor is supposed to turn off after the flame is active?

Comment: Hot surface ignitors are not all the same.  Some are designed to get hot in 15 seconds while others are designed to get hot in 30 seconds.  Perhaps you have the incorrect ignitor for this stove.

Comment: Okay, I don't have reputation to answer this question..  I installed the used ignitor the cranky repair guuy gave me when I showed him the burned out new one.  It works fine.  In my oven, the ignitor stays on for the entire time the flame is on.  I'm not 100% correct, but I believe that's the way my oven's been operating since I've had it.  The flame is actually only barely visible, but there has always been an orange glow from the the oven when the flame is on.  I presume that glow is and always has been the ignitor.  When the used one fails I'll buy the OEM ignitor and hope for the best.